# Angular google map marker

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I add google map with marker on load the marker set up to center,

But when the user change the zoom or move right left the map, the marker position change and the marker move to center and not the same  of the coords that i add on page load

this is my code:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="false" options="options">
        <ui-gmap-marker idkey="'1'"  coords='map.center'
        icon='{url:    "//developers.google.com/.../beachflag.png" }'>
             <ui-gmap-window isiconvisibleonclick="true">
                            <p ng-cloak>Marker Clicked!</p>
             </ui-gmap-window>
         </ui-gmap-marker>
 </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

this is my map object

[image]

My Problem same as here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113161/angular-google-map-marker-position-not-fixed-moving-when-map-moves-how-to-make

How can i add marker that fixed on place and if the user move left right or zoom the map the marker stay on the same original coords.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `ui-gmap-marker` `coords` attribute is a reference to `map.center`, which changes whenever you move the map. You'll want to have an own controller variable for the marker, so it has its own location attribute. Something like this,

Controller:

```
// Map initialization
$scope.map = { center: { latitude: 32.0889, longitude: 34.8357 }, zoom: 16};

// Give the marker its own scope variable, you can attach other info here, too
$scope.marker = {coords: angular.copy($scope.map.center)}
```

HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="false" options="options">
    <ui-gmap-marker idkey="'1'"  coords='marker.coords'
        icon='{url:    "//developers.google.com/.../beachflag.png" }'>
        <ui-gmap-window isiconvisibleonclick="true">
            <p ng-cloak>Marker Clicked!</p>
        </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

EDIT: Forgot angular.copy first. Added plunkers demonstrating both broken and working behaviour.

Broken: http://plnkr.co/edit/nkecrOXm84V6lEVr85Yi?p=preview

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/kvgLSeuKTPo6FKqIFE89?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
This code shows multiple marker in google map.



<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://combinatronics.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapController">

    <map zoom-to-include-markers="true" style="display:block; width:900px; height:500px;">
        <marker ng-repeat="pin in markerData" position="{{pin.latitude}},{{pin.longitude}}" title="{{pin.title}}" on-click="showDetail(pin)"></marker>
        <info-window id="foo-iw">
           <div ng-non-bindable="">
                <h1>{{currentPin.title}}</h1><br/>
                <a href="{{currentPin.url}}">Click Here</a>
           </div>

        </info-window>
    </map>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller('mapController', function (NgMap, $scope, $q, $log) {

        NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
            $scope.map = map;
            //$scope.map.setZoom(13);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0902, -122.636652);
            $scope.map.setCenter(latlng);
        });   

        $scope.currentPin = {title: "",url:""};
        $scope.markerData = [];
        $scope.cityMetaData = [];

        $scope.getCityInfo = function (country) {
            $scope.markerData = [];

            var data = [
                { cityName: ' Petaluma, CA, USA','url':'https://www.flipkart.com/' },
                { cityName: ' Jackson Heights, Queens, NY, USA','url':'https://www.flipkart.com/' },
                { cityName: ' UNICEF 6 Fairbridge Avenue Belgravia, Harare, Zimbabwe','url':'https://www.flipkart.com/' },
            ];


            data.forEach(function (item) {
                var cityData = item;
                $scope.cityMetaData.push(cityData);
                $scope.addressMarker(cityData);
            });
        }


        $scope.showDetail = function (e, pin) {
          $scope.currentPin = pin;
          $scope.map.showInfoWindow('foo-iw', this);
        };

        $scope.hideDetail = function () {
           $scope.map.hideInfoWindow('foo-iw');
        };

        $scope.addressMarker = function (cityItem) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var address = cityItem.cityName;
            var url = cityItem.url;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.markerData.push({
                            "latitude": results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                            "longitude": results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                            "title": results[0].formatted_address
                            ,"url": url
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    $log.info('Geocode was not successful for the following reason:' + status);
                }
            });
        }
        $scope.getCityInfo();




    });
</script>
```